# "Ringing in the New Year (2011→ 2012)" puzzle

Tags: haskell, graph, breadth-first-search

I am  trying to solve the puzzle [RINGING IN THE NEW YEAR](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/holiday/2011/index.html).

> Start at 2011. By moving through the maze and doing any arithmetic operations you encounter, exit the maze with a result of 2012. You may pass through an operation several times, but not twice in a row.
>
> 2011 [image: maze] 2012

My solution is to construct an breadth first search tree of the graph, and go through it, do the arithmetic operations.

In my windows 7 machine, it takes 29s to get the result.

How to make it better? (Improvement of algorithm or better way of compiling)

```
module Main where

import Data.Ratio
import Data.Tree

data Label = Label
  { f1     :: (Rational -> Rational)
  , accept :: Bool
  , f2     :: (Rational -> Rational)
  , value  :: Rational
  , disp   :: [String]
  }

initial = Node (Label (const 2011) False (const 2011) 2011 [""])
               [ Node (Label (const 2011) False (+7) 0 ["+7"]) center1
               ]

label1, label2, label3, label4 :: Label
label1 = Label (+7)         False (/2)          0 ["+7", "/2"]
label2 = Label (/2)         False (+7)          0 ["/2", "+7"]
label3 = Label (subtract 5) True  (*3)          0 ["-5", "*3"]
label4 = Label (*3)         True  (subtract 5) 0 ["*3", "-5"]

tree1, tree2, tree3, tree4 :: Tree Label
tree1 = Node label1 center2
tree2 = Node label2 center1
tree3 = Node label3 center4
tree4 = Node label4 center3

center1, center2, center3, center4 :: Forest Label
center1 = [ tree3, tree4, tree2 ]
center2 = [ tree3, tree4, tree1 ]
center3 = [ tree4, tree1, tree2 ]
center4 = [ tree3, tree1, tree2 ]

travel :: Tree Label -> [Label]
travel t = map rootLabel $
                      concat $ takeWhile (not . null) $
                      iterate (\ts -> concat $ map step ts) [t]

step :: Tree Label -> Forest Label
step (Node l sub) = map update sub
  where
    update (Node l' sub') = Node l'{ accept = (accept l') && ((f1 l') v == 2012)
                                   , value = ((f2 l').(f1 l')) v, disp = disp l ++ disp l'} sub'
    v = value l

main = (print . (\l -> concat (disp l) ++ " = " ++ show (value l))) $ head $ filter accept $ travel initial
```

Comment: Isn't this a homework? If it is, you should tag it as such.

Comment: @zeroos, No, it is not. Just for fun.

Comment: There was [a kind of related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/arithmetic-golf-reach-2011) on PCG last year.

Comment: I'd be tempted to run a kind of meet-in-the-middle search from each end. I can't see an obvious way to do better than a brute force search, but running it as meet-in-the-middle will reduce the total search path length by a factor of two, done twice. Given exponential run time in the path length, that seems like a significant improvement.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this solution that runs in 0.2 seconds on my computer when compiled. It also does a BFS with memoisation. However, it uses two heuristics: Don't divide by two unless the denominator is 1 and don't go above 10000. A more elegant way would be to use a priority queue that prioritises "states" like these. However, using these heuristics does not guarantee an optimal solution.

As a side note, this question might be better for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

```
import Data.Ratio
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Sequence hiding (reverse)

-- Left, Middle, or Right
data Pos = L | M | R
 deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

-- Up/Down Left/Right
data Lbl = UL | UR | DL | DR
 deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

-- The operators in the labels
op :: Lbl -> Rational -> Rational
op UL = (+7)
op UR = (*3)
op DL = (/2)
op DR = (subtract 5)

-- Gives the possible candidates for a position
candidates :: Pos -> [(Pos,Lbl)]
candidates = \p -> case p of M -> map (L,) left ++ map (R,) right
                             L -> map (M,) left
                             R -> map (M,) right
  where right = [UR,DR]
        left  = [UL,DL]

-- The state is the value, position and the last label (cannot revisit it)
type St = (Rational,Pos,Lbl)

-- The memo map, remembers if a state has been visited before and
-- which was the previos state
type Memo = Map St St

-- Is this a solved state?
solved :: St -> Bool
solved (2012,R,_) = True
solved _          = False

-- The initial state
initSt :: St
initSt = (2011,L,DR)  -- ugly hack, say the last label was DR ;)

-- Solve, with a queue of states to visit and a memo map
solve :: Seq St -> Memo -> [St]
solve (viewl -> top@(v,p,l) :< rest) memo
  | solved top = reverse (retrievePath memo top)
  | otherwise  =
     let new = [ (st,top)
               | (p',l') <- candidates p
               -- ^ Get the candidate locations from here
               , l /= l'
               -- ^ Don't go through the same label twice
               , let st@(v',_,_) = (op l' v,p',l')
               -- ^ Calculate the new state
               -- Two heuristics:
               , not (l == DL && denominator v' /= 1)
               -- ^ 1) don't divide by two unless the denominator is 1
               , v' < 10000
               -- ^ 2) don't go above 10000
               , st `M.notMember` memo
               -- ^ Don't revisit a state
               ]
     in  solve (rest >< fromList (map fst new))
               -- ^ Enqueue the new states
               (memo `M.union` M.fromList new)
               -- ^ Add these to the memoization

-- Retrieve the path from the memo map
retrievePath :: Memo -> St -> [St]
retrievePath memo st@(v,p,l)
  | st == initSt = [initSt]
  | otherwise    = st : retrievePath memo (memo M.! st)

-- This is the problem with 2011 and 2012
problem = solve (singleton initSt) (M.singleton initSt initSt)

main = print problem
```

Answer (score 3):

This runs near-instantly on my machine.

I didn't use the `Tree` type, just rolled my own nodes and edges.  I also only used integer division (since none of the operations have the ability to invert that transformation from integral to nonintegral).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
module Main where

import Data.List (group, sort, find, intercalate)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, fromJust)

data Edge = (Int -> Maybe Int) :> Node
data Node = Node { nid :: Int, exit :: Bool, edges :: [Edge] }

instance Eq Node where
  Node n _ _ == Node n' _ _ = n == n'
instance Ord Node where
  Node n _ _ `compare` Node n' _ _ = n `compare` n'

t x y = Just $ x * y
p x y = Just $ x + y
o x y = if y `mod` x == 0 then Just $ y `div` x else Nothing
m x y = Just $ subtract x y

start, start2, start7, mid2, mid3, mid5, mid7, end3, end5 :: Node
start = Node 0 False [ (p 7) :> mid7
                   , (o 2) :> mid2
                   ]

mid7 = Node 1 False [ (o 2) :> start2
                  , (t 3) :> end3
                  , (m 5) :> end5
                  ]

mid2 = Node 2 False [ (p 7) :> start7
                  , (t 3) :> end3
                  , (m 5) :> end5
                  ]

start2 = Node 3 False [ (p 7) :> mid7 ]

start7 = Node 4 False [ (o 2) :> mid2 ]

end3 = Node 5 True [ (m 5) :> mid5 ]

end5 = Node 6 True [ (t 3) :> mid3 ]

mid5 = Node 7 False [ (p 7) :> start7
                  , (o 2) :> start2
                  , (t 3) :> end3
                  ]

mid3 = Node 8 False [ (p 7) :> start7
                  , (o 2) :> start2
                  , (m 5) :> end5
                  ]

step :: Int -> [Node] -> [(Int, [Node])]
step m ns@(Node _ _ es : _) = catMaybes $ map (\(f :> n) -> fmap (,n:ns) (f m)) es

uniq :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
uniq = map head . group . sort

stage :: [(Int,[Node])] -> [(Int,[Node])]
stage = uniq . concatMap (uncurry step)

bfs :: String
bfs = (intercalate "." . map (name . nid) . snd $ result) ++ "$id"
  where result = fromJust $ find (\(m,ns) -> m == 2012 && exit (head ns)) search
        search :: [(Int,[Node])]
        search = concat $ iterate stage [(2011,[start])]
        name 0 = "($ 2011)"
        name 1 = "(+7)"
        name 2 = "(/2)"
        name 3 = "(/2)"
        name 4 = "(+7)"
        name 5 = "(*3)"
        name 6 = "(-5)"
        name 7 = "(-5)"
        name 8 = "(*3)"

main = putStrLn bfs
```